# How to resolve this Import Error for the training code for speech reconstruction from silent audio?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, importerror

I am trying to run the code from this github repository [enter link description here](https://github.com/arielephrat/vid2speech)

In this I have installed all neccessary libraries as specified.
After Preprocessing, when I try to run the train.py code. I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ML Mini Project\vid2speech-master\vid2speech-master\code\train_modell.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Users\mahee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "C:\Users\mahee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>  
    from keras.engine.functional import Functional
  File "C:\Users\mahee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 24, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'
```

I will paste a snippet of my train.py file here, please help me in resolving this error.

I have renamed the train.py to train_modell.py to avoid any clashes with function names.

snippet of train_modell.py:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
import sys
from os.path import isfile, join
import shutil
import h5py
import os.path
import glob
import audio_tools as aud

FRAME_ROWS = 128
FRAME_COLS = 128
NFRAMES = 9
MARGIN = NFRAMES/2
COLORS = 1
CHANNELS = COLORS*NFRAMES
TRAIN_PER = 0.8
LR = 0.01
nb_pool = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 32
DROPOUT = 0.25 
DROPOUT2 = 0.5
EPOCHS = 60
FINETUNE_EPOCHS = 10
activation_func2 = 'tanh'

respath = '../results/'
weight_path = join(respath,'weights/')
datapath = '../dataset/'

def load_data(datapath):
    viddata_path = join(datapath,'viddata.npy')
    auddata_path = join(datapath,'auddata.npy')
    if isfile(viddata_path) and isfile(auddata_path):
        print ('Loading data...')
        viddata = np.load(viddata_path)
        auddata = np.load(auddata_path)
        vidctr = len(auddata)
        print ('Done.')
        return viddata, auddata
    else:
        print ('Preprocessed data not found.')
        sys.exit()

def split_data(viddata, auddata):
    vidctr = len(auddata)
    Xtr = viddata[:int(vidctr*TRAIN_PER),:,:,:]
    Ytr = auddata[:int(vidctr*TRAIN_PER),:]
    Xte = viddata[int(vidctr*TRAIN_PER):,:,:,:]
    Yte = auddata[int(vidctr*TRAIN_PER):,:]
    return (Xtr, Ytr), (Xte, Yte)


def build_model(net_out):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal', input_shape=(CHANNELS, FRAME_ROWS, FRAME_COLS)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU())  
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU())  
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='he_normal'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
absl-py==1.4.0
altgraph==0.17.3
astunparse==1.6.3        
cachetools==5.3.0        
certifi==2022.9.24       
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.0.6
cycler==0.11.0
decorator==4.4.2
distlib==0.3.6
filelock==3.8.0
flatbuffers==23.3.3      
fonttools==4.38.0        
future==0.18.2
gast==0.4.0
google-auth==2.17.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.54.0
h5py==3.8.0
idna==3.4
imageio==2.28.0
imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.8
jax==0.4.8
keras==2.12.0
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.4.4
libclang==16.0.0
Markdown==3.4.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.6.2
ml-dtypes==0.1.0
MouseInfo==0.1.3
moviepy==1.0.3
numpy==1.23.5
oauthlib==3.2.2
opencv-python==4.7.0.72
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==21.3
pefile==2022.5.30
Pillow==9.2.0
platformdirs==2.5.2
proglog==0.1.10
protobuf==4.22.4
psycopg2==2.9.6
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
PyAutoGUI==0.9.53
PyGetWindow==0.0.9
pyinstaller==5.4.1
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.10
PyMsgBox==1.0.9
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyperclip==1.8.2
pypiwin32==223
PyRect==0.2.0
PyScreeze==0.1.28
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytweening==1.0.4
pywin32==306
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.28.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
scipy==1.10.1
six==1.16.0
tensorboard==2.8.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.12.0
tensorflow-intel==2.12.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
termcolor==2.3.0
tf-estimator-nightly==2.8.0.dev2021122109
Theano==1.0.5
tk==0.1.0
tqdm==4.65.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==1.26.12
virtualenv==20.16.5
Werkzeug==2.3.3
win10toast==0.9
wrapt==1.14.1
```

I would like to know what causes this error and how to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi @Maheedhar A, I can see you have installed tensorflow-intel but not tensorflow. You need to install `tensorflow` first (using `pip install tensorflow==2.12`) as keras uses tensorflow in backend which is causing this error. The above mentioned code does not show any error when I tried replicating the error in Google Colab and jupyter notebook with same configuration (Python 3.10, tensorflow 2.12). (Attaching the [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/48ec94c0cfa95b43f8d51fe428c34b4d/76187559.ipynb) here for your reference).